# KML/KMZ file <10MB for global shipping lanes?

Tags: data, kml, route, kmz, marine

I am trying to render an overlay of the world's shipping lanes using google KmlLayer class from the Javascript V3 API but most of the files I find are not rendered because of google's 10MB size limit.

Does anyone know of any helpful KMZ/KML files of a suitable size for world shipping lanes?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a particular KML/KMZ file, but if you're creating the KMZ file yourself you might have some success if you generalize the data to remove vertices. I've never had a problem using KMZ in Google Earth with file sizes larger than 10MB, however I've had plenty of problems with KMZ containing more than 30000 vertices. If you can't generalize the whole dataset to get below 30k, you could try splitting it up into regions to get each below the 30k, create KMZ of each, and then group them back inside a top level KMZ.